# Historical data resources for Indian market

Tags: trading, market-data, historical-data, algorithmic-trading, quantitative

What is the best source for historical EOD data for Indian stock market? The data from Yahoo finance for some companies is not up-to-date and Google finance doesn't provide adjusted close prices. What should I do ? I need the data for quantitative analysis.

Is there a way to calculate adjusted close from Google finance close price series ?

If I'm using the expression (close[n]-close[n-1])/close[n-1] for returns calculations. It will show erroneous data, because of the change in price due to stock split.

Please help me out of this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of options other than Google or Yahoo that I am aware of.

The NSE provides EOD data, as well as 5,2 and 1 minute data. If you're willing to pay for high quality data for your application, this is an excellent choice. http://www.nseindia.com/supra_global/content/dotex/data_products.htm

Quandl provides comparatively clean, free EOD data which might suit your requirements too.
Like, https://www.quandl.com/NSE/BATAINDIA

Answer (score 1):

Per its [help-page](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/finance/historical-prices-sln2311.html) yahoo provides adjusted closing prices on a weekly basis.

If that is not sufficient, you can always calculate adjusted closing prices using [this formula](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/why-does-the-adjusted-closing-price-take-into-account-dividends/4167#4167), however, you would need to know the dividend history of each stock. Those are also available from yahoo finance.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch Indian stocks data from NSEpy.The data available on NESpy are:
1. Daily stock data
2. Stock futures data
3. Stock options data
4. Index futures data
5. Index options data

Example to get daily stock data from NSEpy in Python:

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2019, 30, 7)

data = get_history(symbol='HDFC',start=start,end=end)

data.head()
```

[image]

For more information, you can refer to the [NSEpy](https://nsepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation:

Comment: I think your `end = datetime(2019, 30, 7)` should be `end = datetime(2019, 7, 30)`, since the syntax is `datetime(year, month, day...`.

Comment: what about dividends and stock splits?